# Smartlock integration

Tags: android

I am working on app that needs some sort of authorization: users submit their name and password and server responds with some tokens that then sent as headers in every requests to API. Previously I saved these tokens in AccountManager. And now I'm wondering whether it is possible to integrate with Smartlock. But how to deal with these tokens? Though the user could be logged in mobile version of site I need these tokens to make API requests.
Is it possible to integrate these token authorization and Smartlock?